# How to deal with onnxruntime.InferenceSession invoking many threads?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I use htop to monitor, and after simply running the following python codes in **cpu** device, about 100 thr (threads) have been invoked and kept. I want to reduce the number of threads, but how?

```
import onnxruntime
from time import sleep
sleep(20)
model = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('my.onnx', providers=['CPUExecutionProvider'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage many parameters using the onnxruntime.SessionsOptions(). For example the number of threads :

```
sess_options.intra_op_num_threads = 2
```

More informatons here [ONNX doc](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/performance/tune-performance/threading.html)